# Sql query to multiply two column value to third column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to multiply two columns value to 3rd column. Here is my query:

```
select distinct pr.PSProjectId,sfa.CodePattern, case when sfqd.NCR IS null then 'blank' else sfqd.NCR end as NCR  
,
case when sfqd.NCR !='blank' then 
(Select DATEDIFF(minute,starttime,EndTime) from ShopFloorStatusDetail where ShopFloorActivityId=sfa.ShopFloorActivityId
and StatusId=8
)
else 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,sfs.ShiftStarTime,sfs.shiftendtime)
 end as timediff,
(select COUNT(1) from ShopFloorEmployeeTime where ShopFloorShiftId=sfs.ShopFloorShiftId) as totalemployee

from ShopFloor sf  
inner join Project pr on pr.ProjectId=sf.ProjectId  
inner join ShopFloorActivity sfa on sf.ShopFloorId=sfa.ShopFloorId  
inner join ShopFloorShift sfs on sfs.ShopFloorActivityId=sfa.ShopFloorActivityId  
left join ShopFloorStatusDetail sfsd on sfsd.ShopFloorActivityId=sfs.ShopFloorActivityId  
left join ShopFloorQCDetail sfqd on sfqd.ShopFloorStatusDetailId=sfsd.ShopFloorStatusDetailId  
and sfqd.NCR is not null  
where CAST(sfs.ShiftStarTime as DATE) between '2014/01/06' and '2014/01/07'
```

and output from this query is

```
PSProjectId    CodePattern  NCR   timediff  totalemployee
0000129495     3TMEU       blank        8              1
0000130583     3UA1P       blank        1              1
0000130583     3UA1P       blank       2090            2
```

Now i want to multiply column timediff and totalemployee and show it in a new column.

How do I do this? Please help.

Comment: `SELECT.....,timediff*totalemployee as newcolumn FROM`

Comment: if it was so easy, i would have never posted here query.

Comment: Im not sure you can reuse aliases in select,if not use the whole expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a new column, multiplying the existing expressions:

```
case when sfqd.NCR !='blank' 
     then (Select DATEDIFF(minute,starttime,EndTime) 
             from ShopFloorStatusDetail 
            where ShopFloorActivityId=sfa.ShopFloorActivityId
              and StatusId=8
           )
     else DATEDIFF(MINUTE,sfs.ShiftStarTime,sfs.shiftendtime)
 end 
*
(select COUNT(1) 
   from ShopFloorEmployeeTime 
  where ShopFloorShiftId=sfs.ShopFloorShiftId)
```

Alternatively, wrap the whole existing query in another query, and multiply the calcualted columns:

```
select
    PSProjectId,
    CodePattern,
    NCR,
    timediff,
    totalemployee,
    timediff * totalemployee
from
    (  ...original query here... )
```